# $_FILES empty on large files when using plupload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, plupload

So I'm using plupload http://www.plupload.com/ to upload large files in chunks

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
      runtimes : 'html5, flash, silverlight',
      browse_button : 'upload-btn',
      url : upload_url,
      chunk_size: '200000kb',
     flash_swf_url : '/path/plupload-2.1.1/js/Moxie.swf',
      silverlight_xap_url : '/path/plupload-2.1.1/js/Moxie.xap',
      multipart_params : {fid : fidVar},
    });

    uploader.init();
```

This will upload large files in "chunks" of approximately 200M each and is handled by my backend PHP script

This will perform a POST call per chunk

Now the problem is suppose I try to upload a file that is around 1.7G big...on the first chunk POST call everything seems to work fine

$_FILES get populated accordingly and so is $_POST and I can process the uploaded chunk from $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] and save it in the backend accordingly

Sometimes the second POST call for the second chunk also works fine

But then once you enter the third or fourth POST call to upload the third/fourth chunk of the file, shit starts hitting the fan

$_POST is empty and so is $_FILES...if I inspect the POST call from firebug, the "post" tab displays empty instead of displaying the proper POST data

What could possibly cause this?

I tried debugging into moxie.js which perform the ajax call and the proper information seems to be added to the FormData object accordingly before it gets sent to xhr.send()

Moreover, there seems to be nothing wrong with my php.ini configuration:

```
> max_file_uploads  20  20 
> upload_max_filesize   1024M   1024M
> upload_tmp_dir    no value    no value 
> post_max_size 1024M   1024M
> max_input_time    60  60 
> max_input_vars    100000  100000
```

how can I possibly resolve this issue?

Comment: does it work when you upload a smaller file,for example 500M?

Comment: Try a smaller chunk size. Same exact issue?

Comment: @Young yep 500M file uploaded just fine.......

Comment: @WesleyMurch using smaller chunk size makes more of the POST calls work (ie have their _POST and _SERVER variables populated) however some of the post calls also end up not having their POST/SERVER populated